# c3.js second y axis doesn't scale to data

Tags: javascript, d3.js, c3.js

I'm using c3.js and I need y2 axis so I added to the code :

```
axis: {
        y2: {
            show: true
        }
    }
```

but the ticks do not correspond to my data values : I find 0,5,2,2,1 while my data values go up to 20. When I add :

```
axis: {
            y2: {
                show: true,
                inner: true 
            }
        }
```

It's strange but it gives the right values however my client doesn't want the ticks to be on the inside.
Is it a bug from c3.js ? Could you please help me fix it ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

how about using:

```
axis: {
  y2: {
    tick: {
      values: [100, 1000, 10000]
    }
  }
}
```

OR

```
axis: {
  y2: {
    tick: {
      outer: false
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer however I tried the first solution and I still have the same problem, as for the second I need the tick to be outer so instead I put outer : true and I got the wrong values

Comment: can you share a fiddle may be?

Comment: The data is constructed dynamically that's why I can't but I added a picture of the problem when I have a standard y2 axis. I hope that helps

Comment: Thank you for the fiddle however that is exactly what I have (except that the data is dynamic and the construction of the function c3.generate depends on the data )